# swGenericSaveError when using SolidWorks API to save assembly as part (C++)

Tags: c++, api, com, save, solidworks

I am trying to use the C++ API implementation to save an assembly (.SLDASM) as a part document (.SLDPRT), but I keep getting swGenericSaveError.

Using the following code:

```
void guardarModelo()  
{  
  //Guardar como part  
  wchar_t exportedfilename[MAX_PATH], assemblyname[MAX_PATH], *pext, *pname;  
  long error = 0, warning = 0;  
  VARIANT_BOOL result = 0;  
  CComPtr<IModelDocExtension> swExtension; //Extension (formato de fichero)  
  swUserPreferenceIntegerValue_e part = swSaveAssemblyAsPartOptions; //Opciones de part  

  //Arreglamos la extension y la ubicacion del fichero  
  wcscpy(exportedfilename, filename);  
  pext = wcsrchr(exportedfilename, L'\\') + 1;  
  wcscpy(pext, L"-modelo\\");  
  CreateDirectory(exportedfilename, NULL);  

  wcscpy(assemblyname, filename);  
  pname = wcsrchr(assemblyname, L'\\') + 1;  
  pext = wcsrchr(assemblyname, L'.');  
  wcsncpy(pext, L".SLDPRT\0", 8);  
  wcscat(exportedfilename, pname);  

  CComBSTR sFileName(exportedfilename);  

  swModel->get_Extension(&swExtension);  

  //swApp->SetUserPreferenceIntegerValue(part, swSaveAsmAsPart_AllComponents, &result);  
  swExtension->SetUserPreferenceInteger(swSaveAssemblyAsPartOptions, swDetailingNoOptionSpecified, swSaveAsmAsPart_AllComponents, &result);  

  swExtension->SaveAs(sFileName, swSaveAsCurrentVersion, swSaveAsOptions_Silent, NULL, &error, &warning, &result);  

  if (error == 0)  
  wcout << "Modelo completo guardado como part." << endl;  
  else  
  wcout << "ERROR " << error << " guardando modelo completo como part." << endl;  

}
```

The code works fine when exporting the asssembly to a Parasolid binary (.x_b):

```
void exportarModelo()  
{  
  //Exportar a parasolid  
  wchar_t exportedfilename[MAX_PATH], assemblyname[MAX_PATH], *pext, *pname;  
  long error = 0, warning = 0;   
  VARIANT_BOOL result = 0;  
  CComPtr<IModelDocExtension> swExtension; //Extension (formato de fichero)  
  swUserPreferenceIntegerValue_e parasolid = swParasolidOutputVersion; //Opciones de Parasolid  


  //Arreglamos la extension y la ubicacion del fichero  
  wcscpy(exportedfilename, filename);  
  pext = wcsrchr(exportedfilename, L'\\') + 1;  
  wcscpy(pext, L"-modelo\\");  
  CreateDirectory(exportedfilename, NULL);  


  wcscpy(assemblyname, filename);  
  pname = wcsrchr(assemblyname, L'\\') + 1;  
  pext = wcsrchr(assemblyname, L'.');  
  wcsncpy(pext, L".x_b\0", 5);  
  wcscat(exportedfilename, pname);  


  CComBSTR sFileName(exportedfilename);  

  swModel->get_Extension(&swExtension);  


  //Elegir version de Parasolid y guardar  
  swApp->SetUserPreferenceIntegerValue(parasolid, swParasolidOutputVersion_150, &result);  


  swExtension->SaveAs(sFileName, swSaveAsCurrentVersion, swSaveAsOptions_Silent, NULL, &error, &warning, &result);  


  if (error == 0)  
  wcout << "Modelo completo exportado a Parasolid." << endl;  
  else  
  wcout << "ERROR " << error << " exportando modelo completo a Parasolid." << endl;  


}
```

Anyone has any idea why this isn't working? Is there an alternative way to save all components of an assembly in a single part document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. The key is to use the **ActivateDoc3** method to activate the loaded assembly before saving the document. This takes care of the swGenericSaveError and works great.